# Is vbscript ECMA-compliant?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I tried to Google this but did not get a definitive answer.

Just wanted to know if vbscript supports the ECMA standard supported by JavaScript.

Is **vbscript** ECMA-compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript cannot be ECMA compliant as it is a different language altogether. That does not mean that they both cannot achieve the same end result, given the right environment.

Reference:

Page 265 - VBScript Programmer's Reference
By Adrian Kingsley-Hughes, Kathie Kingsley-Hughes, Daniel Read

---

My thoughts - I guess it would be like asking:

1. Is a rotary engine the same as a piston engine?

   No. A 2 rotor engine has two moving parts, while a normal piston engine has typically over 40 moving parts. It is generally easier to find parts for a piston engine and most main stream stores stock parts suitable for piston engines. It is also generally harder to find rotary specialists. Both propel a vehicle but in very different ways. Is one better than the other? I would be insulting experts if I were to wager my thoughts here.
2. Is the VHS format Betamax compliant?

   No. They use different technology to achieve what may seem like similar results. Typically Betamax standards would allow for 60 minutes of recording whilst VHS would generally allow for around 180 minutes. Is one format better than the other? Again, I would be insulting experts if I were to comment here.